# TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm trying to do a tutorial backbone project with peepcode, but I got stuck.

I am trying to render a view from the console by creating a new view from a collection. Here's my code

```
(function($) {

    window.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({

        isFirstTrack: function(index) {
            return index == 0; 
        },

        isLastTrack: function(index) {
            return index >= this.get('tracks').length - 1; 
        },

        trackUrlAtIndex: function(index) {
            if (this.get('tracks').length >= index) {
                return this.get('tracks')[index].url;
           }
            return null;
        }

    }); 

    window.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Album,
        url: '/albums'
    });

    window.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    window.AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'album',


        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);

            this.template = _.template($('#album-template').html());
        },

        render: function() {
            var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
            return this;
        }
    });

    window.LibraryAlbumView = AlbumView.extend({

    });

    window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'section',
        className: 'library',

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.template = _.template($('#library-template').html());
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },

        render: function() {
            var $albums,
                collection = this.collection;

            $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
            $albums = this.$(".albums");
            collection.each(function(album) {
                var view = new LibraryAlbumView({
                    model: album,
                    collection: collection
                });
                $albums.append(view.render().el);
            });
            return this;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I type `libraryView = new LibraryView({ collection: library })`
 In the console I get this response:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to drill a little deeper. Try commenting out individual lines in LibraryView until the error goes away. Once you've identified the exact line the causes the error you can probably fix it quite easily. Or use a debugger if you're familiar with that. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_oiQYirKuY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the element for the library view doesn't exist in your markup.

This should be true

```
$('#library-template').length == 1;
```

This error can happen if you do:

```
 _.template(null)
 _.template(undefined);
```

Calling `.html()` on an element that doesn't exist returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the `library` variable (that you're using as the value in the constructor argument to `LibraryView`) set to? It's not defined globally, so it's probably `null`. You'd need to first declare that variable:

```
var library = new Albums(),
    libraryView = new LibraryView({ collection: library })
```